# How do you display mean instead of median using boxplot function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, boxplot

Is it possible to display mean instead of median using boxplot function in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 1):

to plot the mean as a mark **over** the `boxplot`:

```
boxplot
...
plot(mean,'d'),'-mo',
               'LineWidth',15,
               'MarkerEdgeColor','k',
               'MarkerSize',20;
```